# Generate all permutations of a list without adjacent equal elements

Tags: python, algorithm, combinatorics

When we sort a list, like

```
a = [1,2,3,3,2,2,1]
sorted(a) => [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```

equal elements are always adjacent in the resulting list.

How can I achieve the opposite task - shuffle the list so that equal elements are never (or as seldom as possible) adjacent?

For example, for the above list one of the possible solutions is

```
p = [1,3,2,3,2,1,2]
```

More formally, given a list `a`, generate a permutation `p` of it that minimizes the number of pairs `p[i]==p[i+1]`.

Since the lists are large, generating and filtering all permutations is not an option.

Bonus question: how to generate all such permutations efficiently?

This is the code I'm using to test the solutions: https://gist.github.com/gebrkn/9f550094b3d24a35aebd

UPD: Choosing a winner here was a tough choice, because many people posted excellent answers. [@VincentvanderWeele](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25285879/989121), [@David Eisenstat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25290780/989121), [@Coady](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25291640/989121), [@enrico.bacis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25286137/989121) and [@srgerg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25401193/989121) provided functions that generate the best possible permutation flawlessly. [@tobias_k](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25286251/989121) and David also answered the bonus question (generate all permutations). Additional points to David for the correctness proof.

The code from @VincentvanderWeele appears to be the fastest.

Comment: Not optimal but fast enough if input is sorted: 0, N - 1, 1, N - 2, 2, N - 3...

Comment: So you care only for *equality*? something like `[1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 5]` is exactly the same as `[1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 5]` by your criterion?

Comment: @Bakuriu: for starters, any "good" permutation is fine, but see the bonus question.

Comment: There cannot be an "efficient" algorithm. Take a list like `[1, 1, 1, ..., 2, 3, 4, ..., N]` with `2N` elements. You can put a number `n > 1` between each pair of consecutive `1` to obtain a good permutation. Then you permute the `N/2` elements and obtain all valid permutations (meaning none is a bad one, but there may be more). The number of such permutations is O(N^2), so you cannot do better than O(N^2). Still better than O(N^3) of the naive approach though.

Comment: @ Adriano Repetti I think 0, N/2, 1, N/2+1, ... is much better.

Comment: Simple in Haskell: `unordered xs = concatMap (\(a,b)->[a,b]) . uncurry zip  . splitAt (div (length xs) 2) $ sort xs`

Comment: @awashburn: simple indeed! )))

Comment: @Bakuriu: Two things: (1) to be clear, your example shows that there can be no efficient algorithm *for the bonus question*.  (2) Enumerating all optimal solutions to your example is O((N/2)!), which is much worse than O(N^2) (i.e. your example is much stronger than you realised :-)

Comment: @j_random_hacker I was obviously referring to the bonus question (since the OP had just pointed that out). And yes, I have no idea why I wrote O(N^2). I had that complexity in mind for other reasonings before, so it probably just stick there.

Comment: To distinguish this question from pure Code Golf, of what possible use could such a sequence be? It ain't monte carlo nor any other stochastic process. It can't be sort algorithm comparison because that's all been done before and this yields uninteresting cases only, and so on.

Comment: @msw: I'm making a website, and there is a row with ads blocks from different providers. I want to arrange them so that no blocks from the same provider stand side by side.

Comment: I wouldn't say that this is "not even close to a duplicate", but the alleged duplicate is a different question, since the distance between identical elements is considered. People who voted to close after WhyCry's comment: please pay more attention in the future.

Comment: This is not about as "unsorted" as possible. A list that has no equal elements could be sorted and you would be ok with it. A better title might be "How can I generate all permutations of a list without neighbored equal elements?".

Comment: @moose: I guess there must be a mathematical term for such a permutation, but I don't know it. In the meantime, your suggestion looks fine to me (BTW, this space is collaborative, feel free to edit everything).

Comment: What happened to the "unsorted as possible"  question? That was an interesting question.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is along the lines of Thijser's currently incomplete pseudocode. The idea is to take the most frequent of the remaining item types unless it was just taken. (See also [Coady's implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25291640/2144669) of this algorithm.)

```
import collections
import heapq


class Sentinel:
    pass


def david_eisenstat(lst):
    counts = collections.Counter(lst)
    heap = [(-count, key) for key, count in counts.items()]
    heapq.heapify(heap)
    output = []
    last = Sentinel()
    while heap:
        minuscount1, key1 = heapq.heappop(heap)
        if key1 != last or not heap:
            last = key1
            minuscount1 += 1
        else:
            minuscount2, key2 = heapq.heappop(heap)
            last = key2
            minuscount2 += 1
            if minuscount2 != 0:
                heapq.heappush(heap, (minuscount2, key2))
        output.append(last)
        if minuscount1 != 0:
            heapq.heappush(heap, (minuscount1, key1))
    return output
```

### Proof of correctness

For two item types, with counts k1 and k2, the optimal solution has k2 - k1 - 1 defects if k1 < k2, 0 defects if k1 = k2, and k1 - k2 - 1 defects if k1 > k2. The = case is obvious. The others are symmetric; each instance of the minority element prevents at most two defects out of a total of k1 + k2 - 1 possible.

This greedy algorithm returns optimal solutions, by the following logic. We call a prefix (partial solution) *safe* if it extends to an optimal solution. Clearly the empty prefix is safe, and if a safe prefix is a whole solution then that solution is optimal. It suffices to show inductively that each greedy step maintains safety.

The only way that a greedy step introduces a defect is if only one item type remains, in which case there is only one way to continue, and that way is safe. Otherwise, let P be the (safe) prefix just before the step under consideration, let P' be the prefix just after, and let S be an optimal solution extending P. If S extends P' also, then we're done. Otherwise, let P' = Px and S = PQ and Q = yQ', where x and y are items and Q and Q' are sequences.

Suppose first that P does not end with y. By the algorithm's choice, x is at least as frequent in Q as y. Consider the maximal substrings of Q containing only x and y. If the first substring has at least as many x's as y's, then it can be rewritten without introducing additional defects to begin with x. If the first substring has more y's than x's, then some other substring has more x's than y's, and we can rewrite these substrings without additional defects so that x goes first. In both cases, we find an optimal solution T that extends P', as needed.

Suppose now that P does end with y. Modify Q by moving the first occurrence of x to the front. In doing so, we introduce at most one defect (where x used to be) and eliminate one defect (the yy).

### Generating all solutions

This is [tobias_k's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25286251/2144669) plus efficient tests to detect when the choice currently under consideration is globally constrained in some way. The asymptotic running time is optimal, since the overhead of generation is on the order of the length of the output. The worst-case delay unfortunately is quadratic; it could be reduced to linear (optimal) with better data structures.

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import permutations
from operator import itemgetter
from random import randrange


def get_mode(count):
    return max(count.items(), key=itemgetter(1))[0]


def enum2(prefix, x, count, total, mode):
    prefix.append(x)
    count_x = count[x]
    if count_x == 1:
        del count[x]
    else:
        count[x] = count_x - 1
    yield from enum1(prefix, count, total - 1, mode)
    count[x] = count_x
    del prefix[-1]


def enum1(prefix, count, total, mode):
    if total == 0:
        yield tuple(prefix)
        return
    if count[mode] * 2 - 1 >= total and [mode] != prefix[-1:]:
        yield from enum2(prefix, mode, count, total, mode)
    else:
        defect_okay = not prefix or count[prefix[-1]] * 2 > total
        mode = get_mode(count)
        for x in list(count.keys()):
            if defect_okay or [x] != prefix[-1:]:
                yield from enum2(prefix, x, count, total, mode)


def enum(seq):
    count = Counter(seq)
    if count:
        yield from enum1([], count, sum(count.values()), get_mode(count))
    else:
        yield ()


def defects(lst):
    return sum(lst[i - 1] == lst[i] for i in range(1, len(lst)))


def test(lst):
    perms = set(permutations(lst))
    opt = min(map(defects, perms))
    slow = {perm for perm in perms if defects(perm) == opt}
    fast = set(enum(lst))
    print(lst, fast, slow)
    assert slow == fast


for r in range(10000):
    test([randrange(3) for i in range(randrange(6))])
```

Answer (score 23):

Pseudocode:

1. Sort the list
2. Loop over the first half of the sorted list and fill all even indices of the result list
3. Loop over the second half of the sorted list and fill all odd indices of the result list

You will only have `p[i]==p[i+1]` if more than half of the input consists of the same element, in which case there is no other choice than putting the same element in consecutive spots (by the pidgeon hole principle).

---

As pointed out in the comments, this approach may have one conflict too many in case one of the elements occurs at least `n/2` times (or `n/2+1` for odd `n`; this generalizes to `(n+1)/2)` for both even and odd). There are at most two such elements and if there are two, the algorithm works just fine. The only problematic case is when there is one element that occurs at least half of the time. We can simply solve this problem by finding the element and dealing with it first.

I don't know enough about python to write this properly, so I took the liberty to copy the OP's implementation of a previous version from github:

```
# Sort the list
a = sorted(lst)

# Put the element occurring more than half of the times in front (if needed)
n = len(a)
m = (n + 1) // 2
for i in range(n - m + 1):
    if a[i] == a[i + m - 1]:
        a = a[i:] + a[:i]
        break

result = [None] * n

# Loop over the first half of the sorted list and fill all even indices of the result list
for i, elt in enumerate(a[:m]):
    result[2*i] = elt

# Loop over the second half of the sorted list and fill all odd indices of the result list
for i, elt in enumerate(a[m:]):
    result[2*i+1] = elt

return result
```

Comment: From my understanding, this is what @jojo [does](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25286188/989121) - not always optimal.

Comment: This fails either for `[0, 1, 1]` or `[0, 0, 1]`, depending on whether you use 0-based or 1-based indices.

Comment: @georg Indeed this is the same approach as in my answer. (Note that Heuster answered before me!). In my code however the steps 2. and 3. are combined, thus optimising the efficiency.

Comment: @flornquake Good catch! It's the good-old off-by-one error I'm afraid. So, this approach is not optimal, as it may have 1 conflict too many.

Comment: @Heuster: thanks! I've [translated your code to python](https://gist.github.com/gebrkn/9f550094b3d24a35aebd#file-tests-py-L112), but the results are not ideal (e.g. `[2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1] -> [1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2]`). Did I make a mistake?

Comment: @georg My bad! Of course, if in a sorted array `a` we have `a[i] == a[i+k]` then there are `k+1` elements the same. So I changed `m=(n+1)//2` to `m=(n+1)//2-1`. Besides, I copied your python code from Github, for future visitors. I hope that's ok :)

Comment: @Heuster: `m=(n+1)//2-1` seems to have broken things, I'm getting `list assignment index out of range` in the last loop.

Comment: @georg Sigh! I'm really sorry, this is the worst trial and error approach ever... I didn't realize you used `m` in two spots. Reverted the `-1` in `m's` definition and made it explicit in the first loop. That won't work for the empty list, though.

Comment: @Heuster: all lights are green! "0 faults".

Comment: Equivalent to this: `a.sort(); half=len(a)/2; for i in range(half): {yield a[i]; yield a[half+i];} if len(a)%2==1: {yield a[-1]}`

Answer (score 10):

The algorithm already given of taking the most common item left that isn't the previous item is correct.  Here's a simple implementation, which optimally uses a heap to track the most common.

```
import collections, heapq
def nonadjacent(keys):
    heap = [(-count, key) for key, count in collections.Counter(a).items()]
    heapq.heapify(heap)
    count, key = 0, None
    while heap:
        count, key = heapq.heapreplace(heap, (count, key)) if count else heapq.heappop(heap)
        yield key
        count += 1
    for index in xrange(-count):
        yield key

>>> a = [1,2,3,3,2,2,1]
>>> list(nonadjacent(a))
[2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Good example on how NOT to write algorithms in Python. It's simple but required like 30 minutes just to digest syntax.

Answer (score 8):

You can generate *all* the 'perfectly unsorted' permutations (that have no two equal elements in adjacent positions) using a recursive backtracking algorithm. In fact, the only difference to generating all the permutations is that you keep track of the last number and exclude some solutions accordingly:

```py
def unsort(lst, last=None):
    if lst:
        for i, e in enumerate(lst):
            if e != last:
                for perm in unsort(lst[:i] + lst[i+1:], e):
                    yield [e] + perm
    else:
        yield []
```

Note that in this form the function is not very efficient, as it creates lots of sub-lists. Also, we can speed it up by looking at the most-constrained numbers first (those with the highest count). Here's a much more efficient version using only the `counts` of the numbers.

```py
def unsort_generator(lst, sort=False):
    counts = collections.Counter(lst)
    def unsort_inner(remaining, last=None):
        if remaining > 0:
            # most-constrained first, or sorted for pretty-printing?
            items = sorted(counts.items()) if sort else counts.most_common()
            for n, c in items:
                if n != last and c > 0:
                    counts[n] -= 1   # update counts
                    for perm in unsort_inner(remaining - 1, n):
                        yield [n] + perm
                    counts[n] += 1   # revert counts
        else:
            yield []
    return unsort_inner(len(lst))
```

You can use this to generate just the `next` perfect permutation, or a `list` holding all of them. But note, that if there is *no* perfectly unsorted permutation, then this generator will consequently yield *no* results.

```py
>>> lst = [1,2,3,3,2,2,1]
>>> next(unsort_generator(lst))
[2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
>>> list(unsort_generator(lst, sort=True))
[[1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3], 
 ... 36 more ...
 [3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1]]
>>> next(unsort_generator([1,1,1]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

To circumvent this problem, you could use this together with one of the algorithms proposed in the other answers as a fallback. This will guarantee to return a perfectly unsorted permutation, if there is one, or a good approximation otherwise.

```py
def unsort_safe(lst):
    try:
        return next(unsort_generator(lst))
    except StopIteration:
        return unsort_fallback(lst)
```

Comment: This uses O(N^2) memory... for each element in the permutation you are doing a copy of the list for the recursive call. Also, being recursive, it fails with "small" lengths.

Comment: @Bakuriu Agreed, that's what I meant with "not optimized for efficiency"... although I have to admit that I did not except O(n^2) space, but you are right... I'll try to improve it.

Comment: O(N^2) is always behind the back when you have a resursion such as `T(n+1) = something + T(n)`.

Comment: @tobias_k: could you post a function for just one perm, for testing?

Comment: @georg Sure: `next(unsort2(collections.Counter(a)))` ;-) But since this algo generates all the possibilities, why not check them all? Its only 38 for that 7 elemented test list.

Comment: @georg Then there might be no "perfect" permutation. The algo finds all the permutations with no adjacent same numbers, but if there is no such permutation, it fails. What list are you testing with?

Comment: @georg Well, in that case you might use my algo to find all the 'perfect' permuations, if any, and fall back to one of the others if there are none.

Comment: @tobias_k: I've updated the gist - your code seems to provide best results so far. I guess `sum(counts.values())` can be optimized.

Comment: @georg Yes, you could instead pass the number of remaining elements as another parameter. And I guess you still need a good fall-back algorithms in case there is no perfect solution...

Answer (score 5):

Here is a good algorithm:

1. First of all count for all numbers how often they occur. Place the answer in a map.
2. sort this map so that the numbers that occur most often come first.
3. The first number of your answer is the first number in the sorted map.
4. Resort the map with the first now being one smaller.

If you want to improve efficiency look for ways to increase the efficiency of the sorting step.

Comment: Yes, this is what @tobias_k did. Seems to work well!

Comment: @georg It's a bit different... I use the counter only to reduce space complexity, but I do not test the numbers by any specific order (thought this might be another speed-up). What's different is that my solution always yield all the 'perfect' permutations, _if any_, while this should yield the best (?) solution (perfect or not).

Comment: This pseudocode isn't quite right; if the item counts are 5 x, 2 y, 2 z, then it will needlessly put x's together. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25290780/2144669) for a fix.

Comment: Agreed. For e.g. [1,1,1,2,3] this will produce e.g. [1,1,2,1,3] instead of [1,2,1,3,1].

Comment: Step 3 is actually counter-productive. If a number is common (at least two more entries than the next most frequent number), step 3 will use that number twice in a row, without any justification.

Answer (score 5):

In python you could do the following.

Consider you have a sorted list `l`, you can do:

```
length = len(l)
odd_ind = length%2
odd_half = (length - odd_ind)/2
for i in range(odd_half)[::2]:
    my_list[i], my_list[odd_half+odd_ind+i] = my_list[odd_half+odd_ind+i], my_list[i]
```

These are just in place operations and should thus be rather fast (`O(N)`).
Note that you will shift from `l[i] == l[i+1]` to `l[i] == l[i+2]` so the order you end up with is anything but random, but from how I understand the question it is not randomness you are looking for.

The idea is to split the sorted list in the middle then exchange every other element in the two parts.

For `l= [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]` this leads to `l =  [3, 1, 4, 2, 5, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5]`

**The method fails to get rid of all the `l[i] == l[i + 1]` as soon as the abundance of one element is bigger than or equal to half of the length of the list.**

While the above works fine as long as the abundance of the most frequent element is smaller than half the size of the list, **the following function also handles the limit cases** (the famous off-by-one issue) where every other element starting with the first one must be the most abundant one:

```
def no_adjacent(my_list):
    my_list.sort()
    length = len(my_list)
    odd_ind = length%2
    odd_half = (length - odd_ind)/2
    for i in range(odd_half)[::2]:
        my_list[i], my_list[odd_half+odd_ind+i] = my_list[odd_half+odd_ind+i], my_list[i]

    #this is just for the limit case where the abundance of the most frequent is half of the list length
    if max([my_list.count(val) for val in set(my_list)]) + 1 - odd_ind > odd_half:
        max_val = my_list[0]
        max_count = my_list.count(max_val)
        for val in set(my_list):
            if my_list.count(val) > max_count:
               max_val = val
               max_count = my_list.count(max_val)
        while max_val in my_list:
            my_list.remove(max_val)
        out = [max_val]
        max_count -= 1
        for val in my_list:
            out.append(val)
            if max_count:
                out.append(max_val)
                max_count -= 1
        if max_count:
            print 'this is not working'
            return my_list
            #raise Exception('not possible')
        return out
    else:
        return my_list
```

Comment: Thanks! This fails for `[3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2]` (returns `[2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3]`, should be `(3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2)`) -- see the gist

Comment: @georg sorry, my bad I forgot a `+1`. Try again now.

Comment: Still problems, `[1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1]` => `[3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1]`

Comment: @georg as I pointed out, it works as long as the most abundant is present less than half the length of the list which is not the case in this example.

Comment: @georg So I added the part handling the of-by-one error. This part is not particularly fast (about the same as the algorithm suggested by Thijser), although it will be run only for rare cases.

Comment: Many thanks for your efforts, but the last version still yields invalid solutions. For example, `[3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]` -> `[2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1]`, while a perfect solution is possible: `(3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1)`. Feel free to download the gist and test for yourself.

Comment: @georg: again my bad, forgot to account for odd list lengths. :( Fixed the issue :)

Comment: @georg: Tested and working with 0 faults. In terms of time this should be the fastest one, since if we are not in the limit case, it runs in `O(N)`. In the limit case it runs as fast as the other working algorithm.

Answer (score 5):

In answer to the bonus question: this is an algorithm which finds all permutations of a set where no adjacent elements can be identical. I believe this to be the most efficient algorithm conceptually (although others may be faster in practice because they translate into simpler code).  It doesn't use brute force, it only generates unique permutations, and paths not leading to solutions are cut off at the earliest point.

I will use the term "abundant element" for an element in a set which occurs more often than all other elements combined, and the term "abundance" for the number of abundant elements minus the number of other elements.
*e.g. the set `abac` has no abundant element, the sets `abaca` and `aabcaa` have `a` as the abundant element, and abundance 1 and 2 respectively.*

1. Start with a set like:

> aaabbcd

2. Seperate the first occurances from the repeats:

> firsts: abcd
>   repeats: aab

3. Find the abundant element in the repeats, if any, and calculate the abundance:

> abundant element: a
>   abundance: 1

4. Generate all permutations of the firsts where the number of elements after the abundant element is not less than the abundance: (so in the example the "a" cannot be last)

> abcd, abdc, acbd, acdb, adbc, adcb, bacd, badc, bcad, <s>bcda</s>, bdac, <s>bdca</s>,
>   cabd, cadb, cbad, <s>cbda</s>, cdab, <s>cdba</s>, dabc, dacb, abac, <s>dbca</s>, dcab, <s>dcba</s>

5. For each permutation, insert the set of repeated characters one by one, following these rules:

> 5.1. If the abundance of the set is greater than the number of elements after the last occurance of the abundant element in the permutation so far, skip to the next permutation.
>   *e.g. when permutation so far is `abc`, a set with abundant element `a` can only be inserted if the abundance is 2 or less, so `aaaabc` is ok, `aaaaabc` isn't.*
>
> 5.2. Select the element from the set whose last occurance in the permutation comes first.
>   *e.g. when permutation so far is `abcba` and set is `ab`, select `b`*
>
> 5.3. Insert the selected element at least 2 positions to the right of its last occurance in the permutation.
>   *e.g. when inserting `b` into permutation `babca`, results are `babcba` and `babcab`*
>
> 5.4. Recurse step 5 with each resulting permutation and the rest of the set.

```
EXAMPLE:
set = abcaba
firsts = abc
repeats = aab

perm3  set    select perm4  set    select perm5  set    select perm6

abc    aab    a      abac   ab     b      ababc  a      a      ababac  
                                                               ababca  
                                          abacb  a      a      abacab  
                                                               abacba  
                     abca   ab     b      abcba  a      -
                                          abcab  a      a      abcaba  
acb    aab    a      acab   ab     a      acaba  b      b      acabab  
                     acba   ab     b      acbab  a      a      acbaba  
bac    aab    b      babc   aa     a      babac  a      a      babaca  
                                          babca  a      -
                     bacb   aa     a      bacab  a      a      bacaba  
                                          bacba  a      -  
bca    aab    -
cab    aab    a      caba   ab     b      cabab  a      a      cababa  
cba    aab    -
```

This algorithm generates unique permutations. If you want to know the total number of permutations (where `aba` is counted twice because you can switch the a's), multiply the number of unique permutations with a factor:

> F = N<sub>1</sub>! * N<sub>2</sub>! * ... * N<sub>n</sub>!

where N is the number of occurances of each element in the set. For a set `abcdabcaba` this would be 4! * 3! * 2! * 1! or 288, which demonstrates how inefficient an algorithm is that generates all permutations instead of only the unique ones. To list all permutations in this case, just list the unique permutations 288 times :-)

Below is a (rather clumsy) implementation in Javascript; I suspect that a language like Python may be better suited for this sort of thing. Run the code snippet to calculate the seperated permutations of "abracadabra".

```js
// FIND ALL PERMUTATONS OF A SET WHERE NO ADJACENT ELEMENTS ARE IDENTICAL
function seperatedPermutations(set) {
    var unique = 0, factor = 1, firsts = [], repeats = [], abund;

    seperateRepeats(set);
    abund = abundance(repeats);
    permutateFirsts([], firsts);
    alert("Permutations of [" + set + "]\ntotal: " + (unique * factor) + ", unique: " + unique);

    // SEPERATE REPEATED CHARACTERS AND CALCULATE TOTAL/UNIQUE RATIO
    function seperateRepeats(set) {
        for (var i = 0; i < set.length; i++) {
            var first, elem = set[i];
            if (firsts.indexOf(elem) == -1) firsts.push(elem)
            else if ((first = repeats.indexOf(elem)) == -1) {
                repeats.push(elem);
                factor *= 2;
            } else {
                repeats.splice(first, 0, elem);
                factor *= repeats.lastIndexOf(elem) - first + 2;
            }
        }
    }

    // FIND ALL PERMUTATIONS OF THE FIRSTS USING RECURSION
    function permutateFirsts(perm, set) {
        if (set.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < set.length; i++) {
                var s = set.slice();
                var e = s.splice(i, 1);
                if (e[0] == abund.elem && s.length < abund.num) continue;
                permutateFirsts(perm.concat(e), s, abund);
            }
        }
        else if (repeats.length > 0) {
            insertRepeats(perm, repeats);
        }
        else {
            document.write(perm + "<BR>");
            ++unique;
        }
    }

    // INSERT REPEATS INTO THE PERMUTATIONS USING RECURSION
    function insertRepeats(perm, set) {
        var abund = abundance(set);
        if (perm.length - perm.lastIndexOf(abund.elem) > abund.num) {
            var sel = selectElement(perm, set);
            var s = set.slice();
            var elem = s.splice(sel, 1)[0];
            for (var i = perm.lastIndexOf(elem) + 2; i <= perm.length; i++) {
                var p = perm.slice();
                p.splice(i, 0, elem);
                if (set.length == 1) {
                    document.write(p + "<BR>");
                    ++unique;
                } else {
                    insertRepeats(p, s);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // SELECT THE ELEMENT FROM THE SET WHOSE LAST OCCURANCE IN THE PERMUTATION COMES FIRST
    function selectElement(perm, set) {
        var sel, pos, min = perm.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < set.length; i++) {
            pos = perm.lastIndexOf(set[i]);
            if (pos < min) {
                min = pos;
                sel = i;
            }
        }
        return(sel);
    }

    // FIND ABUNDANT ELEMENT AND ABUNDANCE NUMBER
    function abundance(set) {
        if (set.length == 0) return ({elem: null, num: 0});
        var elem = set[0], max = 1, num = 1;
        for (var i = 1; i < set.length; i++) {
            if (set[i] != set[i - 1]) num = 1
            else if (++num > max) {
                max = num;
                elem = set[i];
            }
        }
        return ({elem: elem, num: 2 * max - set.length});
    }
}

seperatedPermutations(["a","b","r","a","c","a","d","a","b","r","a"]);
```

Comment: thanks for this! will see whether this can be shortened a bit in javascript.

Answer (score 4):

The idea is to sort the elements from the most common to the least common, take the most common, decrease its count and put it back in the list keeping the descending order (but avoiding putting the last used element first to prevent repetitions when possible).

This can be implemented using [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html):

```
from collections import Counter
from bisect import bisect

def unsorted(lst):
    # use elements (-count, item) so bisect will put biggest counts first
    items = [(-count, item) for item, count in Counter(lst).most_common()]
    result = []

    while items:
        count, item = items.pop(0)
        result.append(item)
        if count != -1:
            element = (count + 1, item)
            index = bisect(items, element)
            # prevent insertion in position 0 if there are other items
            items.insert(index or (1 if items else 0), element)

    return result
```

### Example

```
>>> print unsorted([1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1])
[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3]

>>> print unsorted([1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2])
[2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2]
```

Comment: This fails with, for example: `[1, 1, 2, 3]` where there are solutions such as `[1, 2, 1, 3]`.

Comment: Yes, I just realized that, sorry

Comment: Thanks! This doesn't always produce the optimal result, e.g for `[1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2]` it returns `[2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2]` (1 fault), while the ideal is `(2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2)`) -- see the gist.

Comment: @georg True, nice catch, I've updated it keeping the simple principle it uses.

Comment: @enrico.bacis: thanks! The new version works flawlessly. I've updated the gist. Too bad I can't upvote you anymore.

Comment: @georg Wonderful, it would be nice to time the solutions in the gist to check also the performance of each solution

Comment: @enrico.bacis: done. Unfortunately, yours is not the fastest. ((

Answer (score 2):

1. Sort the list.
2. Generate a "best shuffle" of the list using [this algorithm](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Best_shuffle#Swap_if_it_is_locally_better_algorithm)

It will give the minimum of items from the list in their original place (by item value) so it will try, for your example, to put the 1's, 2's and 3's away from their sorted positions.

Comment: I've tried `best_shuffle` and it generated `[1,1,1,2,3] -> [3, 1, 2, 1, 1]` - not ideal!

Answer (score 2):

Start with the sorted list of length n.
Let m=n/2.
Take the values at 0, then m, then 1, then m+1, then 2, then m+2, and so on.
Unless you have more than half of the numbers the same, you'll never get equivalent values in consecutive order.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I think this is what @Heuster implemented.

Answer (score 2):

Please forgive my "me too" style answer, but couldn't [Coady's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25291640/2144669) be simplified to this?

```
from collections import Counter
from heapq import heapify, heappop, heapreplace
from itertools import repeat

def srgerg(data):
    heap = [(-freq+1, value) for value, freq in Counter(data).items()]
    heapify(heap)

    freq = 0
    while heap:
        freq, val = heapreplace(heap, (freq+1, val)) if freq else heappop(heap)
        yield val
    yield from repeat(val, -freq)
```

**Edit:** Here's a python 2 version that returns a list:

```
def srgergpy2(data):
    heap = [(-freq+1, value) for value, freq in Counter(data).items()]
    heapify(heap)

    freq = 0
    result = list()
    while heap:
        freq, val = heapreplace(heap, (freq+1, val)) if freq else heappop(heap)
        result.append(val)
    result.extend(repeat(val, -freq))
    return result
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to work fine (except that I'm on py2 and the function should return a list).

Comment: @georg Ok, I added a python 2 version that returns a list.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Count number of times each value appears
> 2. Select values in order from most frequent to least frequent
> 3. Add selected value to final output, incrementing the index by 2 each time
> 4. Reset index to 1 if index out of bounds

```
from heapq import heapify, heappop
def distribute(values):
    counts = defaultdict(int)
    for value in values:
        counts[value] += 1
    counts = [(-count, key) for key, count in counts.iteritems()]
    heapify(counts)
    index = 0
    length = len(values)
    distributed = [None] * length
    while counts:
        count, value = heappop(counts)
        for _ in xrange(-count):
            distributed[index] = value
            index = index + 2 if index + 2 < length else 1
    return distributed
```