# How to shuffle a array of objects with no two duplicates next to each other?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, shuffle

I need to shuffle an array of objects that I receive from an API. The array will have the same occurrence of repeated objects.

Valid input:

- ["a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","c","c","c","c"]
- ["a", "a", "b", "b"] or ["b", "b", "a", "a"]

Invalid input:

- ["a","a","a","a","b","c"]
- ["a", "b", "a", "b"]

After shuffling:

- The objects at i and i + 1 should be different
- Every time the array is shuffled it should generate a new valid solution

Valid outputs:

- b,a,c,b,a,c,a,c,b,a,c,b
- c,a,b,a,b,c,a,c,b,a,b,c
- c,b,a,c,b,a,c,b,a,c,b,a

Invalid outputs:

- c,c,a,b,b,a,c,b,a,c,b,a

I started using Fisher–Yates for an initial shuffle and then validate if the solution is valid. 
This brute force approach is working once I have a small set, but as the input grows it gets useless.
Is there an efficient way to generate a random permutation without leaving duplicates next to each other?

[Efficient algorithm for ordering different types of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37452547/efficient-algorithm-for-ordering-different-types-of-objects) gave an insight on how to keep the objects of the same kind far from each other, unfortunately, I'll run into the same solution/pattern If I try to shuffle it again.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32366585/4271233 generates all possible permutations that satisfy the "no two duplicates next to each other", but I'd sadly need to generate all of them and then pick randomly one

Comment: What have *you* tried?

Comment: You need an array shuffled, and I need a question. Other than *solve this please* :) [ask]

Comment: @luk2302, I'm using Fisher–Yates and then validating if the solution is valid. This brute force approach is working once I have a small set, but as the input grows it gets useless

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficient algorithm for ordering different types of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37452547/efficient-algorithm-for-ordering-different-types-of-objects)

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37040164/how-to-shuffle-a-character-array-with-no-two-duplicates-next-to-each-other

Comment: the input array is ordered? [a,b,a,b] is a valid input?

Comment: @elbraulio, the objects of the same type will be received together, thus, just [a,a,b,b] or [b,b,a,a] are valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is not optimal but you can start from this

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] input = new String[]{
                "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c"
        };
        // here we'll generate the output
        String[] output = new String[input.length];
        // how many different characters do we have?
        int characters = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < input.length; i++) {
            if (!input[i - 1].equals(input[i])) {
                break;
            } else {
                characters++;
            }
        }
        // how many times each character appears
        int times = input.length / characters;
        // different characters to shuffle
        String[] toShuffle = new String[characters];
        int m = 0;
        while (times * m < input.length) {
            toShuffle[m] = input[times * m];
            m++;
        }
        // for each position in output
        for (int i = 0; i < output.length;) {
            // define a list with all different characters
            List<String> remain = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(toShuffle));
            // set a random character without repetition
            int j = 0;
            while (j < characters) {
                int pos = 0;
                // after {characters} we have a chance of repetition so we check
                if(i % characters == 0 && i != 0) {
                    do {
                        pos = Double.valueOf(Math.random() * remain.size())
                                .intValue();
                    } while (output[i-1].equals(remain.get(pos)));
                } else {
                    pos = Double.valueOf(Math.random() * remain.size())
                            .intValue();
                }
                // assign a character
                output[i] = remain.get(pos);
                // remove from possible chars to not repeat
                remain.remove(pos);
                j++;
                i++;
            }
        }
        // this is the solution
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(output));
    }
```