# Generate list of dictionaries without adjacent dictionary key/values equal

Tags: python, lambda

I have a sorted list based on the value for key `name` as below:

```
s = [{'name': 'Bart', 'age': 12}, {'name': 'Bart', 'age': 19}, {'name': 'Bart', 'age': 1},{'name': 'Homer', 'age': 30}, {'name': 'Homer', 'age': 12},{'name': 'Simpson', 'age': 19}]
```

I want to arrange the elements of the list such that dictionaries with the same value for key `name` **do not** occur one after the other.

Required output:

```
[{'name': 'Bart', 'age': 12}, {'name': 'Homer', 'age': 30}, {'name': 'Simpson', 'age': 19}, {'name': 'Bart', 'age': 19}, {'name': 'Homer', 'age': 12}, {'name': 'Bart', 'age': 1}]
```

**OR**

```
[{'name': 'Bart', 'age': 12}, {'name': 'Homer', 'age': 30}, {'name': 'Bart', 'age': 19}, {'name': 'Homer', 'age': 12}, {'name': 'Bart', 'age': 1},{'name': 'Simpson', 'age': 19}]
```

To get either one of the required outputs I tried using `map` and `lambda`
The idea was to compare every `name` element with the next elements `name` and if they don't match, swap the values and return the resulting list.

Below is the code which I was trying:

```
map(lambda x: x if x['name']!=next(iter(x))['name'] else None, s)
```

One thing that did not work is that `next(iter(x)` did not return the next element. I also want to know why and if the solution can be achieved using `map` and `lambda` ?

Comment: This is not well-posed. For example, if you have 3 Homers and 1 Bart, that's not possible.

Comment: What if it isn't a sorted list?
Then the ideal solution would be homer, bart, homer , homer.

I only want to separate them as much as I can. Cases where it cannot be avoided, it is fine.

Comment: Related, if not exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25285792/1639625

Comment: @tobias_k: Thanks! this seems helpful. I now need to do the same for a list of dictionaries.

Comment: `next(iter(x))` will create a _new_ `iter` and get the `next` element from that, i.e. it will _always_ return the _first_ element of the iterable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote this according to your requirements, though it is not as condensed:

```
s = [{'name': 'Bart', 'age': 12}, {'name': 'Bart', 'age': 19}, {'name': 'Bart', 'age': 1},
    {'name': 'Homer', 'age': 30}, {'name': 'Homer', 'age': 12},{'name': 'Simpson', 'age': 19}]

res=[]

for m,n in zip(s, reversed(s)):
    if m!=n:
        res.append(m)
        res.append(n)
    else:       
        res.append(m)
    if len(res)==len(s):
        break

print res
```

It makes use of the fact that you already have the sorted list.

Comment: This seems good!
I like the way you used the sorted and the reverse list to get to the solution.
Will test for a few cases.

Comment: This does not always work. Try with the (also sorted) list `s = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3]` It will mix the `1`s and `3`s just fine, but then clump all the `2`s together.

Comment: @Vaulstein I am sorry about my answer. I will try to come up with a better solution.