# How to distribute the elements of an array in specific order

Tags: arrays

So supposing I have this array

```
$arr = array(0 =>"joy", 1=>"boss",2=>"salt",3=>"man",4=>"fish",5=>"bye",6=>"bye",7=>"bye");
```

I want to reorder the array to look something like this

```
$arr = array(0 =>"bye", 1=>"boss",2=>"bye",3=>"man",4=>"bye",5=>"fish",6=>"salt",7=>"joy");
```

I'm trying to avoid the shoffle function because of the probability of getting something like **1=>"bye",2=>"bye"** which is what I'm trying to avoid completely.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you are looking for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25285792/generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-without-adjacent-equal-elements

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate all permutations of a list without adjacent equal elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25285792/generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-without-adjacent-equal-elements)

Comment: Unfortunately no. And I should mention that I am working with php.